# Batch file to extract all rows where values in column meets criteria

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to extract all rows from a CSV where column P equals any of the below 3 strings, retaining the header.

Roaming GST-Free Call Charges

Roaming GST-Free SMS Charges

Roaming GST-Free GPRS Charges

I have no idea how to program batch files but I can normally with enough google searching find something that does something similar then fiddle with it to get what I want but this time I need some help. After a bunch of searching  and fiddling I ended up with the below (just trying to get one of the criteria working) but it only extracts the header.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "header="<"report.csv"
>"reportroam.csv" echo.%header%
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=, tokens=1-16*" %%a in ("report.csv") do (
  if "%%p"=="Roaming GST-Free Call Charges" (
    >>"reportroam.csv" echo.%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n,%%o,%%p,%%q,%%r,%%s
  )
)
```

Here are some examples of what I'm trying to extract.

```
28/01/2017,"9142321123",,"0497321123",,31/12/2016,"11:11:00","0000000000","FRANCE",,"00:00:00",0.000,"N",0.0000,"U-SMS","Roaming GST-Free SMS Charges",,,"No Hierarchy",,,,,,,,,,
28/01/2017,"9142321123",,"0497321123",,31/12/2016,"11:22:00","61452321123","FRANCE",,"00:01:00",0.000,"N",0.0000,"U-ROA","Roaming GST-Free Call Charges",,,"No Hierarchy",,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: One problem you will have is that the FOR /F command treats consecutive delimiters as one which can then throw off the correct token you need to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't likely to be another column containing the required strings, then why not just use `FindStr`.

```bat
FindStr /I /C:"Roaming GST-Free Call Charges" /C:"Roaming GST-Free SMS Charges" /C:"Roaming GST-Free GPRS Charges" "report.csv">>"reportroam.csv"
```

You can even split the long line to make it look better:

```bat
FindStr /I^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free Call Charges"^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free SMS Charges"^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free GPRS Charges"^
 "report.csv">>"reportroam.csv"
```

**Edit**
As an after thought, if you have a known unique string in your header you could do it all in one go:

```bat
@(FindStr /I^
 /C:"Unique Column Header String"^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free Call Charges"^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free SMS Charges"^
 /C:"Roaming GST-Free GPRS Charges"^
 "report.csv")>"reportroam.csv"
```

Comment: The closing parenthesis seems to be missing. The header could be extracted with a separate `set /p "header="<report.csv`

Comment: Cheers, @LotPings I'm blaming the little robot in android for stealing it.